# Flask Many to Many relationship sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: failed to locate a name

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

When trying to get a many to many relationship working I keep getting the following error:

**sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper|User|Users'. Original exception was: When initializing mapper Mapper|User|Users, expression 'Device' failed to locate a name ("name 'Device' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the  class after both dependent classes have been defined.**

I have looked over all the sqlalchemy documents and reviewed multiple links on many to many but no luck.  I am sure its a naming or importing issue, but have not found a solution yet

I removed some of the code that I don't feel is related

## Users.py

```
from random import SystemRandom
from backports.pbkdf2 import pbkdf2_hmac, compare_digest
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from devices.models import Device

user_device = db.Table('UserDevice', db.Model.metadata,
                   db.Column('userID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.userID')),
                   db.Column('deviceID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Device.deviceID')))


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

  __tablename__ = 'Users'
  __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
                  'extend_existing': True}

  id = db.Column('userID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  # Relationship to UserDevice association table
  user_device = relationship('Device',
                             secondary=user_device,
                             backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

## Device.py

```
class Device(db.Model):

  __tablename__ = 'Device'
  __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
                  'extend_existing': True}

  id = db.Column('deviceID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  date_created = db.Column('deviceDateCreated', db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
  date_modified = db.Column('deviceDateModified', db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
  device_created_user = db.Column('deviceCreatedUser', db.String, default='App Server')
  device_last_updated_user = db.Column('deviceLastUpdatedUser', db.String, default='App Server', onupdate=current_user)

  #Serial Number
  serial_number = db.Column('deviceSerialNumber', db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)

  #Sampling Interval
  sampling_interval = db.Column('deviceSamplingInterval', db.Integer, default=60, nullable=False)

  # Relationship to Device Status Table
  device_status_id = db.Column('deviceStatusID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('DeviceStatus.deviceStatusID'))

  # New instance instantiation procedure
  def __init__(self, serial_number):
    self.serial_number = serial_number
    self.device_status_id = 1

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<Device %r>' % self.serial_number
```

Image of Database Model:

[image: Image of Database Model]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't provide enough information to solve this problem.  The problem turned out to be using the db variable created by calling SQLAlchemy.  I created a python file just for the database called database.py.  The mistake I made was in User\models.py I called the following **import from database import db** and in Device\models.py I called **from app import db**.  This caused the db.Model to not function properly and also wouldn't create the user tables when calling create_all().  Hope this helps someone in the future.

**Database.py**

```
from flask_influxdb import InfluxDB
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
influx_db = InfluxDB()
influx_db_client = None


def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    from users.models import User, UserStatus, UserDevice
    from devices.models import Device, DeviceStatus
    db.Model.metadata.drop_all(bind=db.engine)
    db.Model.metadata.create_all(bind=db.engine)
```

**Devices\models.py**

```
from app import db
from flask_login import current_user
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
import enum


class DeviceStatusType(enum.Enum):
    INACTIVE = "Inactive"
    ACTIVE = "Active"

# Define a Device model
class Device(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'Device'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = db.Column('deviceID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created = db.Column('deviceDateCreated', db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    date_modified = db.Column('deviceDateModified', db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
    device_created_user = db.Column('deviceCreatedUser', db.String(128), default='App Server')
    device_last_updated_user = db.Column('deviceLastUpdatedUser', db.String(128), default='App Server', onupdate=current_user)

    #Serial Number
    serial_number = db.Column('deviceSerialNumber', db.Integer, nullable=False, unique=True)

    #Sampling Interval
    sampling_interval = db.Column('deviceSamplingInterval', db.Integer, default=60, nullable=False)

    # Relationship to Device Status Table
    device_status_id = db.Column('deviceStatusID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('DeviceStatus.deviceStatusID'))

    users = relationship("User", secondary="userDevice")

    # New instance instantiation procedure
    def __init__(self, serial_number):
        self.serial_number = serial_number
        self.device_status_id = 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Device %r>' % self.serial_number
```

**users\models.py**

```
from random import SystemRandom
from backports.pbkdf2 import pbkdf2_hmac, compare_digest
from flask_login import UserMixin, current_user
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from devices.models import Device

import enum

# Import the database object (db) from the main application module
# We will define this inside /app/__init__.py in the next sections.
from app import db


class UserStatusType(enum.Enum):
    INACTIVE = "Inactive"
    ACTIVE = "Active"


# Define a User model
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'User'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = db.Column('userID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_created = db.Column('userDateCreated', db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    date_modified = db.Column('userDateModified', db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
    user_created_user = db.Column('userCreatedUser', db.String(128), default=current_user)
    user_last_updated_user = db.Column('userLastUpdatedUser', db.String(128), default=current_user, onupdate=current_user)

    # First Name
    first_name = db.Column('userFirstName', db.String(128), nullable=False)

    # Last Name
    last_name = db.Column('userLastName', db.String(128), nullable=False)

    # User Name
    user_name = db.Column('userUserName', db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)

    # Email
    email = db.Column('userEmailAddress', db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)

    # Password
    _password = db.Column('userPassword', db.LargeBinary(128))
    _salt = db.Column('userSalt', db.LargeBinary(128))

    # Relationship to User Status table
    user_status_id = db.Column('userStatusID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('UserStatus.userStatusID'))

    # Relationship to UserDevice association table
    devices = relationship("Device", secondary="userDevice")

    @hybrid_property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    # In order to ensure that passwords are always stored
    # hashed and salted in our database we use a descriptor
    # here which will automatically hash our password
    # when we provide it (i. e. user.password = "12345")
    @password.setter
    def password(self, value):
        # When a user is first created, give them a salt
        if self._salt is None:
        self._salt = bytes(SystemRandom().getrandbits(8))
        self._password = self._hash_password(value)

    def is_valid_password(self, password):
        """Ensure that the provided password is valid.

        We are using this instead of a ``sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator``
        (which would let us write ``User.password == password`` and have the incoming
        ``password`` be automatically hashed in a SQLAlchemy query)
        because ``compare_digest`` properly compares **all***
        the characters of the hash even when they do not match in order to
        avoid timing oracle side-channel attacks."""
        new_hash = self._hash_password(password)
        return compare_digest(new_hash, self._password)

    def _hash_password(self, password):
        pwd = password.encode("utf-8")
        salt = bytes(self._salt)
        buff = pbkdf2_hmac("sha512", pwd, salt, iterations=100000)
        return bytes(buff)

    # New instance instantiation procedure
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, user_name, email, password):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.user_name = user_name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.user_status_id = 2

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User #{:d}>".format(self.id)
```

Comment: Update your question instead of answering your own answer if it doesn't answer the question.